# Can't get Join working in my Sql Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have two tables.

```
Transaction
------------
TransactionId
Date
Amount
Quantity
ProductCode
etc
```

-and-

```
Product
-----------
ProductId
Description
ProductCode
etc
```

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will give me the transactions with the description of the product with them.

I have this so far but it's not even close to compiling. I'm not understanding SQL syntax to well.

```
USE SuburbanPortal;
SELECT [CompanyCode]
      ,[Status]
      ,[Branch]
      ,[ProductCode]
      ,[TransactionBranch]
      ,[AccountNumber]
      ,[ReferenceNumber]
      ,[TransactionDate]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[Amount]
      ,[SalesTax]
  FROM [Company].[Transaction]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Company].[Transaction] ON
    [Company].[Transaction].[ProductCode] = [Company].[Products].[ProductCode]
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Add [Product].Description in the columns you select ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why aren't you using an `INNER JOIN`? Also, you're joining `[Transaction]` on `[Transaction]` instead of `[Transaction]` on `[Product]`.

```
SELECT  T.ProductCode
        ,T.[Field1]
        ,T.[Field2]
        ,P.[Field1]
        ,P.[Field2]
FROM    [Company].[Transaction] T
        INNER JOIN [Company].[Product] P
            ON T.[ProductCode] = P.[ProductCode];
```

Comment: k that makes sense to me now and it works great. Thanks for clarifying this for me!

Comment: @ErocM. Pleasure - don't forget to upvote and mark as correct :)

Comment: yup had to wait 4 minutes. You got the upvote now :) thx again

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
USE SuburbanPortal;
SELECT [CompanyCode]
      ,[Status]
      ,[Branch]
      ,p.[ProductCode]
      ,[TransactionBranch]
      ,[AccountNumber]
      ,[ReferenceNumber]
      ,[TransactionDate]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[Amount]
      ,[SalesTax]
  FROM [Company].[Transaction] as t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Company].[Product] as p ON
    p.[ProductCode] = t.[ProductCode]
```